# Jade Object Format for easier editing

Tags: javascript, pug

I'm populating some mixins via objects and arrays directly in jade.

The Jade-Syntax is (obviously) extremly restrictive, so the objects are pretty messy to edit and put content in.

Is there anyway to get from this:

```
-var data = [["content", "more content"],["another sub-array", "this is a pain to edit"],["especially if the strings get longer", "yep"]]
```

To this?

```
-var data = [
   ["Data", "more Data"],
   ["...", "you get the idea"]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally found a solution:

```
-
   var data = [
      ["Data", "more Data"],
      ["...", "you get the idea"]
   ]
```

Does the trick.